# I lost the Windows partition after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with Unified key

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

As I remember the unified key, but the problem is i search this forum and the whole youtube and evrything possibe to recover my partition .

This is exactly what happened:

1. I got a live Dvd to install the ubuntu, but before installation of ubuntu it asked whether you want to replace the windows 8, and i thought that it will delete the windows c folder and will replace the ubuntu latest 16  !!
2. Then i installed the ubuntu  with warning that it will remove the windows and replace the ubuntu.
3. And after sucessful installation of ubuntu now i faced the really painful situation that i didn't have my partition of 1 terabyte.  It has to be 2 partions on my windows.
4. After getting this problem i searched and researched the whole internet and i got nothing but somewhere it mentioned that use **testdisk** but the fact is i don't have any idea with the terminal window .
5. Since i seached officially the software database but there is so such software found. i downloaded it from the internet from their site but i don't know how to install a zip file even after extracting it.
6. But i got the **Gparted** and after opening it says like this:

[image: Gparted screenshot]

I have many important things on my drive so I really need to recover it!

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty screwed. Firstly you followed the steps in the Ubuntu installer which you seem to understand said it would delete your data, which it did. That alone would likely leave your data unrecoverable. However, in addition you then formatted an encrypted LUKS partition, which upon creation wipes the entire partition with random data.

TL;DR - Deleted all your data then replaced it with random, virtually the most unrecoverable/secure thing possible.